# Flask login is not working outside my initial flask Login route.?

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I am utilizing a react frontend and a flask backend for my app. I am trying to utilize flask_login to authenticate and track user information throughout my various api calls. I have worked through the flask login docs and cannot for the life of me figure out my user information is not being remembered between route calls.

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__='users'
    id= db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(50))
    date_joined = db.Column(db.Date, default=datetime.utcnow)
    # role = db.Column(db.String(50), defualt="user")
    def __init__(self, username, email, password):
        self.username = username
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
    def to_json(self):
        return {
            'id' : self.id,
            'username' : self.username, 
            'email' : self.email,
            'date_joined' : self.date_joined,
        }

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'Login'
login_manager.session_protection = "strong"
login_serializer = URLSafeTimedSerializer(app.secret_key)


@login_manager.user_loader
@cross_origin(supports_credentials=True)
def load_user(user_id):
    print(user_id, file=sys.stderr) #This isn't printing anything. I am not sure this route is being hit
    return User.query.get(user_id)



@app.route('/Login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@cross_origin(supports_credentials=True)
def Login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        session.pop('user_id', None)
        session['username'] = request.get_json()['username']
        session['password'] = request.get_json()['password']
        user = db.session.query(User).filter(User.username==session['username']).first()
        if user and user.password == session['password']:
            session['user_id'] = user.id
            login_user(user, remember=True, force=True)
            # print(current_user, file=sys.stderr) #This successfully prints out a user
            return jsonify(current_user.id)
        else:
            return jsonify(-99999)
    return '''
        <form method="post">
            <p><input type=text name=username>
            <p><input type=submit value=Login>
        </form>
    '''
```

[image]

Now when I try to access my current_user information with a separate route call, I get nothing. When I test if current_user.is_authenticated:...it is not. I don't know what is happening here. Is the session getting reset? Am I logging out of the user after logging in? I have no idea.

```
@app.route('/AnswerQuestion/<int:question_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@cross_origin(supports_credentials=True)
def AnswerQuestion(question_id):
    # question = Question.query.get(question_id)
    print( current_user.get_id(), file=sys.stderr)
    return jsonify(question.to_json())
```

returns
[image]

Comment: I'm new to this package...just read some bits on the documentation. Your code seems to be 100% matching their example...leaving me to think that this is not so much a backend issue but maybe an issue related to the cookies namely the cross origin variable REMEMBER_COOKIE_DOMAIN. I would debug this in some place where I could inspect the cookies. Hope it helps.

Comment: Flask login works in a different model (MVC) where the session is maintained. the Api is stateless between call. You need to use a token to identify the user who is requesting the call. you can use a package called flask_praetorian for this. check https://flask-praetorian.readthedocs.io/en/latest/flask_praetorian.html